# is there a way to view registered services in an OSGi application?

Tags: list, service, osgi

I have an OSGi application running Equinox.  I'd like to see the services that are provided by the application.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It depends whether you mean interactively, using an OSGi shell, or programmatically from your application.

**Interactively**

You can use the [Equinox console](http://www.vogella.com/articles/OSGi/article.html#osgiconsole_commands). See 'services'.  To only see the services you have deployed you need to use an LDAP filter. Here's an example:

```
(objectClass=my.package.name.*)
```

Also see @Neil Bartlett's answer which might be easier as you can just constrain by bundle id (assuming you know it, but that's easy to find).

**Programatically**

Use the ServiceTracker approach. [Neil also wrote all about this](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t91059.rhtml), so make sure to give him your upvotes too :)

Comment: it seems to show the eclipse osgi services running.  I'd like to see the services from my osgi application that I have deployed.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Again, you need to use a filter to whittle them down. Also, in some consoles (I'm not sure about the Equinox console) you can filter by source bundle... Neil's second code sample is an example of this.

Answer (score 15):

From the gogo shell type:

```
inspect cap service
```

That will show all services registered by all bundles. If you want to show services for a specific bundle then type:

```
inspect cap service <id>
```

Where `<id>` is the numeric bundle ID of the bundle you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

By far, and I mean by far, the best way to **see** your services and thousands details more is using [Apache Felix Webconsole](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-web-console.html) and then installing [XRay](https://jpm4j.org/#!/p/sha/1E4A5D92C46D7EC829C537471068ED7FBF7B9433//0.0.0). You might want to read my [first](http://softwaresimplexity.blogspot.fr/2012/05/x-rays-for-osgi.html) and [second blog](http://softwaresimplexity.blogspot.fr/2012/07/xray-again.html) about this bundle.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to just start a particular service that is already registered, but not started and would like to start it dynamically, you could get the bundle using:

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("com.example.com.class");
```

//Then start the bundle

```
bundle.start();
```

//Check for the services references

```
ServiceReference<IExampleService> serviceReference = b.getBundleContext().getServiceReference(IExampleService.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [API docs][1] you can call `getContext().getAllServiceReferences(clazz, filter)` method to get a list of all services that were registered under the specified class and match the specified filter expression. Passing `null` on both parameters will get all services.