# How do I get a list of all currently registered OSGi services?

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle

My Java based project is currently running in an OSGi container, where other projects register their OSGi services for others to use. If I know a service is currently registered, I can simply query, with the 'BundleContext' builtin method:

```
getContext().getServiceReference(LogService.class.getName());
```

However, I'd like to be able to query for all OSGi services registered in the context at that moment. I've looked into the available methods for `BundleContext`, but could not find anything there that would suit my needs. I am not looking to actual use the list of registered services to use the service object, but simply obtain the names of the registered services; I do not believe this would violate OSGi principles.

EDIT: I am not using Eclipse or Equinox in my dev environment.

EDIT: If accessing the OSGi services is not possible, or not recommended, with Java, I'd be open to just looking at the registered services via command line if that is possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848839/is-there-a-way-to-view-registered-services-in-an-osgi-application

Comment: @spaniard I will update my question to include that I am not using Equinox (or Eclipse)

Comment: If you use Gogo: `$ allservicereferences null null`. If you use it a lot, you can make an alias: `as = { allservicereferences null null }`. Typing `as` gives you the list then. You can then of course also pipe it through `grep` if you want to find a specific service: `$ as | grep Package`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [API docs](http://www.knopflerfish.org/releases/current/docs/javadoc/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html#getAllServiceReferences(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) you can call `getAllServiceReferences(null, null)` method to get a list of all services:

> **getAllServiceReferences**

```
ServiceReference<?>[] getAllServiceReferences(java.lang.String clazz,
                                             java.lang.String filter)
                                               throws InvalidSyntaxException
```

> Returns an array of ServiceReference objects. The returned array of
> ServiceReference objects contains services that were registered under
> the specified class and match the specified filter expression.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - clazz - The class name with which the service was
>   registered or null for all services.
> - filter - The filter expression or
>   null for all services.

Comment: Notice that `getAllServiceReferences` is returning also services that are not compatible with your class space. I.e. you cannot cast them to their advertised type. `getServiceReferences` only shows the ones that are compatible.